# Vectorized arguments in function

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have created the following function in R:

```
f<-function(t) {
  if (t<0){
    f<-0
    return(f)
  } else {
    f<-(2*t)/((1+t^2)^2)
    return(f)
  }
}
```

The function works fine, but when I try to operate with it or plot it, I get the following error:

> In if (t < 0) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I have tried to use if-else, as some other post suggested, but I cannot get any improvement.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: *The function works fine, but when I try to operate with it or plot it, I get the following error:* ... Please set up a [MCVE]. We need to see the data, how you call this function with input, and how you plot its return.

Comment: It should work as an `ifelse` without any need for a function of its own. Can you show an example of how you tried with `ifelse`? and a reproducible example as asked for by Parfait?